# Python: determine if running inside a .app bundle or not?

Tags: python, py2app

I'm working with py2app on Python 2, and was wondering if there's a way to detect from code whether my app is running as part of a compiled .app file, or as a standalone script.

This is important because some of my code dynamically loads a .dylib file. When running natively as a script, this code runs fine; however, when running inside the .app, I get something like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../python/game/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 316, in <module>
    _run()
  File ".../python/game/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 311, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
  File ".../python/game/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import game
  File "game.pyc", line 10, in <module>
  File "gui.pyc", line 5, in <module>
  File "audio/__init__.pyc", line 2, in <module>
  File "audio/pybass.pyc", line 65, in <module>
  File "ctypes/__init__.pyc", line 365, in __init__
OSError: dlopen(...python/game/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages.zip/audio/libbass.dylib, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    .../python/game/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages.zip/audio/libbass.dylib: stat() failed with errno=20
2013-07-15 02:50:21.146 main[10040:707] main Error
```

I'm thinking the best way would be to move the .dylib file outside of the library and into the Resources, then dynamically load it from there - but in order to do this I need to detect in code whether I'm running in the .app or not, and if so, look in a different location for the library (namely, the Resources folder of the app bundle)

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Py2app sets sys.frozen to "macosx_app" (for application bundles).

A way to avoid your problem is to use the "packages" option:

```
setup(
  ...
  options={
     'py2app': {
        'packages': ['audio'],
      }
  }
)
```

This includes the entire "audio" package in the application bundle as a directory instead of adding it to the site-packages zipfile. That way you don't have to detect whether or not you're in a application bundle.